# Html in Python communicating with JavaScript in Python

Tags: javascript, html, python-2.7, web-applications

I have an html form that places text field data into a Javascript array.  The code is shown here:http://jsbin.com/maniwu/3/edit?html,js,output.

```js
var message = [];

var receiverInput = document.getElementById("Receiver");
var classificationInput = document.getElementById("Classification");
var titleInput = document.getElementById("Title");
var senderInput = document.getElementById("Sender");
var dateInput = document.getElementById("Date");

var messageBox = document.getElementById("display");

function insert() {
  message.push(receiverInput.value);
  message.push(classificationInput.value);
  message.push(titleInput.value);
  message.push(senderInput.value);
  message.push(dateInput.value);
  clearAndShow();
}

function clearAndShow() {
  // Clear our fields
  receiverInput.value = "";
  classificationInput.value = "";
  titleInput.value = "";
  senderInput.value = "";
  dateInput.value = "";

  // Show our output
  messageBox.innerHTML = "";

  messageBox.innerHTML += "Sent Header " + message + "<br/>";
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <form>
    <input id="Receiver" type="text" placeholder="Receiver" />
    <input id="Classification" type="text" placeholder="Classification" />
    <input id="Title" type="text" placeholder="Title" />
    <input id="Sender" type="text" placeholder="Sender" />
    <input id="Date" type="text" placeholder="Date" />
    <input type="button" value="Save/Show" onclick="insert()" />
  </form>
  <div id="display"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

But I want each embedded in Python 2.7 (windows, IDE: spyder) as shown below. How do I get them to communicate?

```js
import js2py

js = ""
"

function classCollection() {
  var message = [];

  var receiverInput = document.getElementById("Receiver");
  var classificationInput = document.getElementById("Classification");
  var titleInput = document.getElementById("Title");
  var senderInput = document.getElementById("Sender");
  var dateInput = document.getElementById("Date");

  var messageBox = document.getElementById("display");

  function insert() {
    message.push(receiverInput.value);
    message.push(classificationInput.value);
    message.push(titleInput.value);
    message.push(senderInput.value);
    message.push(dateInput.value);
    clearAndShow();
  }

  function clearAndShow() {
    receiverInput.value = "";
    classificationInput.value = "";
    titleInput.value = "";
    senderInput.value = "";
    dateInput.value = "";


    messageBox.innerHTML = "";

    messageBox.innerHTML += "Sent Header " + message + "<br/>";
  }
  document.write(message)
}
classCollection()

""
".replace("
document.write ", "
return ")

result = js2py.eval_js(js)

print result
```

```html
import webbrowser f = open('classInformation.html','w') records = """
<html>

<body>
  <form>
    <input id="Receiver" type="text" placeholder="Receiver" />
    <input id="Classification" type="text" placeholder="Classification" />
    <input id="Title" type="text" placeholder="Title" />
    <input id="Sender" type="text" placeholder="Sender" />
    <input id="Date" type="text" placeholder="Date" />
    <input type="button" value="Save/Show" onclick="insert()" />
  </form>
  <div id="display"></div>
</body>

</html>""" f.write(records) f.close() webbrowser.open_new_tab('classInformation.html')
```

Comment: Are you using any frameworks?

Comment: I am open to using flask, but wanted to see if I could do this without at the moment.

Comment: Yes you can but pointless to do it without a framework. Unless you have some requirement that is not met by any of the frameworks. I doubt that though.